# Extracted LM Hashes doesnt match actual password

Tags: authentication, hash, windows-10, ntlm

I'm new to LM Hashing and Windows authentication, and I'm having problems with LM hashes.

I've created 2 accounts with the password "123", and both of them have different hashes, and none of the hashes match any online LM Calculator.

```
aaa:1005:C4EE3658F332B6C7FF1D33F62B106E84:4CF3088135D600E4911B98627744ED4F:::

abc:1006:4101BCC1A99F2B15F1E6855C0C6E105C:5FFFE78ED912250FCCBBFBCB9D685288:::
```

These are the hashes I've got from pwdump7, same passwords, different hashes.
Are the hashes salted or anything like that?

Comment: The LM hashing algorithm relies on the OEM code page of the system (see step 3 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAN_Manager#LM_hash_details). Were both these accounts created on the same windows installation, and were the language settings the same for both?

Comment: Ive created both of the accounts at the same day, in my local computer, without changing the language.
And thats what I dont understand, why differente hashes? lol

Comment: I'm not familiar with this problem, but here's some discussion about hashes being stored differently after an update to Windows 10: https://github.com/Neohapsis/creddump7/issues/2